# Debuggers throwing "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.wrappers.json'; 'werkzeug.wrappers' is not a package"

Tags: python, flask, anaconda, spyder, vscode-debugger

A piece of code that worked fine in the past now throws the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.wrappers.json'; 'werkzeug.wrappers' is not a package

whenever I issue the command

```
from flask import Flask
```

while  developing and debugging.

This even happens in the Flask `__init__.py` script if I run it in *either the Spyder or VSCode* debuggers.

Weirdly my Flask application still runs when I `flask run` from the console (Anaconda) and navigate my website.

The working directories all look OK, and I never had this problem before, I can't debug anymore.

I don't know if this is relevant but I uninstalled flask-bootstrap last week, and I notice that when I now try to upgrade flask with pip or conda I get error message `ImportError: cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index'`.

[image: Errors when try to upgrade flask]

Can anyone suggest anything.

**MORE DETAILS**
I am running a typical Flask application. Here is the console when I start my app, I can go to `localhost:5000` and it works.
[image]

This console is running an `__init__()` function that loads up Flask and other dependencies, this script starts like so.
[image]

When I go to either the Spyder or VSCode debugger and run the same `__init__()` script I immediately get the error in the title, this.
[image]

It fails on the `from flask import...` statement trying to load werkzeug packages, Flask is built on jinja2 and werkzeug.

This all worked fine before, the only thing I have done is pip uninstall flask-bootstrap, and bootstrap is showing in error messages whenever I now use pip.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling Flask by running `pip uninstall Flask` and then installing it again by running `pip install Flask --no-cache-dir`

Also, the command to upgrade an existing package is `pip install -U <package_name>` or `pip install --upgrade <package_name>`

Comment: When I run the uninstall I get the same bunch of error messages as in the screenshot above. Looks like I can't uninstall it???

Comment: Could you try upgrading pip by using `pip install -U pip`?

Comment: Tried all of that and other pip commands, same error in all cases.

Comment: It should be significant that i can launch my flask app and website with no problems but can't run the same thing within a script, and get errors pointing to missing packages.

Comment: Could you share the script and the directory from where you run it?

Comment: OK I have added some more details to my question.